# Why is WP_Query not working with category_name?

Tags: wp-query

Why on earth is this piece of code not working?

```
    $my_query = new WP_Query('category_name=feature');
    while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
        echo 'test';
    endwhile;
```

I've tried with `Feature` and `feature`, no difference.
I need to get post by category name.

Any help appreciated.

**update**

This is not working either: `$my_query = new WP_Query('cat=3');`

**code**

```
// index.php

<?php
    include_once('header.php');
?>

<div id="fp-slider-container" class="blue-gradient">
    <div class="main-content-container">
        <?php
        query_posts( 'cat=3&posts_per_page=5' );

        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
            echo 'test';
        endwhile;


        ?>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    include_once('footer.php');
?>
```

Comment: I'll ask the obvious first: do you definitely have at least one post in that category?

Comment: he he, yes. I got 3 :)

Comment: Can you provide the complete context that this query is being used in?

Comment: @Pippin here you go

Comment: You do not want to use query_posts(). Does WP_Query return anything if you don't specify a category?

Answer (score 8):

A common pitfall is the fact that:

> category_name takes the **category SLUG** NOT the **name** as attribute

This is often mistaken.

Answer (score 2):

instead of hacking index.php why not use the pre_get_posts filter?

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'filter_homepage_posts');
function filter_homepage_posts($query) {
    $limit_number_of_posts = 5;
    $featured_category_id = get_cat_id('Reviews'); // by cat name...
    if ($query->is_home) {
        $query->set('cat', $featured_category_id);
        $query->set('showposts', $limit_number_of_posts);
    }
  return $query;
}
```

copied from: http://www.seanbehan.com/intercepting-the-wordpress-loop

should also work like this since technically the query passes by reference

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'filter_homepage_posts');
function filter_homepage_posts( $query) {
    $limit_number_of_posts = 5;
    $featured_category = 'bacon-category'; // by cat slug...
    if ($query->is_home) {
        $query->set('category_name', $featured_category);
        $query->set('showposts', $limit_number_of_posts);
    }
  return $query;
}
```

Comment: There is no hack. The index.php is whatever you make it to be, so I don't think your solution is the best solution.

Comment: of course index.php is whatever you'd like but obliterating the query object only to make another query is inefficient.  with pre_get_posts you adjust the query before it is run, so you only query the database once instead of twice with your code.  unless, i misunderstood your code and this is a secondary loop?  in which case you have to make a second query and i would recommend get_posts() since it always gives me less stress than with WP_query.

Answer (score 0):

As Hexodus mentioned, `category_name` actually requires a category slug.

If you're determined to use the actual category name as an input, then you can do something like this:

```
$args['category_id'] = get_cat_ID('Category Name');
```

or this:

```
$args['category_name'] = (get_category(get_cat_ID('Category Name'))) -> slug;
```

---

**Documentation:**

get_cat_ID: [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_cat_ID), [Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_cat_id/)

get_category: [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category), [Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_category/)

WP_Query: [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query), [Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)

get_posts: [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts), [Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/)